# Post to Facebook Page via ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I've seen [this](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Quick%20Start%20Guides) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile) but before I sink a ton of time into it, I want to know if what I'm trying to do is possible. I have a Page on FB (not a profile, but a Page for business, websites, etc) and I want to post a story to it via my site automatically. I don't want to do anything else but that. I don't want to create an app (if I don't have to), just post to a Page. Is there an easy way to do this, or is this super complicated?

Also, if I have to build an app, what's the simplest way to go about this (the other guy's question was never answered)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to get a page access token.  Simply use the user access token for an admin of the page and call `me/accounts` There you will find a list of all the pages and apps admined by that user.  Find the page, and in that object will be the page access token.   Use that page access token and HTTP POST to `me/feed` with the post parameters set.

See also:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to control a web browser.  The script could log in then post the message...  Use a library like WatiN to script the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are either going to have to make a Facebook Application, use franks method, or do some sniffing and figure out how the publisher works and login / post with cURL and cookies.

Also there is a application called "Blog RSS Feed Reader" if you wanted to go the RSS route.