# Posting to a Facebook (fan) page wall

Tags: php, facebook

I have a blog (wordpress) and a facebook fan-page for my blog (with more than 1 fan!). I would like to post a message to my FB wall, every time I post something on my blog. Preferrably PHP.

The same question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile), but this question isn’t going anywhere. The question dates from march, but Facebook has updated their API since. The FB documentation gives three different methods for posting to the wall, but I cannot figure out which is the easiest/best one to use.

**Does anyone have a link to a full tutorial or a short walktrough how to get this done?**

(Currently, I’ve got the Ping.fm app setup, who gets its data from twitterfeed. The drawback is that the links get shortened, and Facebook cannot get the first picture and full title.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API posting to a Facebook Fanpage (not sure if it is to wall specifically) success claimed (and explained in reasonable detail) over on this comment:

http://getsatisfaction.com/pingfm/topics/posting_updates_to_facebook_fan_pages_api_supports_it#reply_1038558

Comment: Looks good. I've ran out of time to try it for this or next week, but Its on the schedule (somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the standard "Imported Sites" feature that reads your blog's RSS feed? Get to it from Wall -> Options (below share box) -> Settings -> Blog/RSS under Imported Sites.

See http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2885/facebook_import_blogs_rss_feeds_without_third_party_applications/ for more information.

Comment: It imports the whole blog post and links to the internal facebook page containing the post. I want a direct link from the wall to my site.