# post to facebook wall - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i have created an application where user can post message to their own wall !
this is my code

```
try {
$facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);
$facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;
$fetch = array('friends' =>
array('pattern' => '.*',
'query' => 'select uid2 from friend where uid1={$user}'));

$message = 'Hello There ...';
if ($facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message)) //149th line
echo 'message posted successfully';
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo $e . '<br />';
}
```

it returns an error Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::stream_publish() in /home/webshine/public_html/tutorials/fb/example.php on line 149
what is wrong ?

Comment: i have read similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them helped !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to post on wall you must use `api` method of facebook object.

like this.

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed','post',$params);
```

You're using an old SDK methods apparently.

here is some more code

[How do you post to the wall on a facebook page (not profile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile)

Comment: i downloaded the latest SDK from github ! can you tell me more on your code $facebook->api('/me/feed','post',$params);
HOW TO USE THEM PROPERLY ?

Comment: i got this **Error Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /home/webshine/public_html/tutorials/fb/facebook.php on line 543**

Comment: you must be authorized to post on the wall. 
here is the simple example of how to authorize.
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/readme.md