# How to Post on FB app users wall through API code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I have created a facebook app and need to post on all users FB WAll, who have authorized app to post on there behalf.

i.e, A new event organized somewhere, So through App, admin can post on every App Users FB Wall about the event.

I was using Graph API, however its not working.

Any Pointers/ Guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what platform are u working upon, js or php??

Comment: Using php for my site

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an api call with parameters to post on the users wall.

Edit.:

Here is the below linked example, with some explanation:

```
<?php
 $attachment = array(
'message' => 'this is my message',
'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
'description' => 'this is a description',
'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif'
);
?>
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
```

The `$attachment` array contains the parameters of the wall post and the `$facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);` make the call and returns the result into `$result`.

Here you can find the source: [How do you post to the wall on a facebook page (not profile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile)

Comment: Please provide sample code with your explanation of how it works, instead of links to examples. You could post this in a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing to user's wall in JS SDK:

```
var body = 'Status Test';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error) {
       alert('Error occured');
   } else {
       alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
   }
});
```

[EDIT]
In Php

```
 $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                array(                      
                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
             ));
```